# Using the file path following askopenfilename using tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter

What I'm trying to do:

1. User chooses two files using the two 'open file' buttons
2. File paths of chosen files are displayed so the user can review and change if need be
3. User presses a third button to run other code that fetches the files and analyses them

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import Entry

######################################################
#Build the interface window
######################################################
window = Tk()
window.title('Tkinter Open File Dialog')
window.resizable(False, False)
window.geometry('800x100')
intro = Label(window, text="let's find the data and template")
intro.grid(column=0,row=0)

#Button 1: Browse for the JM file
def JMfileBrowser():
    stfiletypes = (('text files', '*.xlsx'),('All files', '*.*'))
    path= filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=stfiletypes)
    JMFilePath = Label(window, width=100,text=path)
    JMFilePath.grid(column=1,row=2)

#Button 2: Browse for the QRG file
def QRGfileBrowser():
    stfiletypes = (('text files', '*.xlsx'),('All files', '*.*'))
    path= filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=stfiletypes)
    QRGFilePath = Label(window, width=100,text=path)
    QRGFilePath.grid(column=1,row=4)
    #The label in the interface updates, but I don't know how to retrieve the label to use in the program later
#fetch the files for analysis
def fetch_files():
    #let's just start by printing the filepath of selected files
    print(QRGFilePath.cget("text"))
    print(JMFilePath.cget("text"))

#Add buttons and boxes to store values
#A lot of repetition here - find a way shorten this :\

#Label 1: JM File path
JMFilePath = Label(window, width=100,text="select a file")
JMFilePath.grid(column=1,row=2) 

#Label 2: QRG File path
QRGFilePath = Label(window, width=100,text="select a file")
QRGFilePath.grid(column=1,row=4)

#Button 1: Find the JM file
jmfindfile = Button(window, text="Browse JM file", command=JMfileBrowser,width=20) 
jmfindfile.grid(column=0,row=2)

#Button 2: Find the QRG file    
QRGfindfile = Button(window, text="Browse QRG template file", command=QRGfileBrowser,width=20)
QRGfindfile.grid(column=0,row=4)

#Button 3: Fetch the files
fetchFiles = Button(window, text="Run Reports", command=fetch_files,width=20)
fetchFiles.grid(column=0,row=5)

window.mainloop()
```

What should happen:
The code above creates a dialogue box with three buttons. and two labels.
Buttons 1 and 2 prompt the user to find a file
Labels 1 and 2 should store the file path of the selected files
Button 3 then fetches the files so that I can analyse them in some way.

What actually happens:
When button 3 is pressed, the code should print the file path of the two files found when buttons 1 and 2 were pressed. "select a file" is actually printed.

How can I do this-I'm a novice programmer, so easy to understand explanations please. I'm learning too, so any side tips on how to improve the my code writing appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Are you asking *how do you get the file path from a Tkinter filedialog*, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your browse functions you repeat the code that creates the labels that hold the paths :

```
def JMfileBrowser():
    stfiletypes = (('text files', '*.xlsx'),('All files', '*.*'))
    path= filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=stfiletypes)
    JMFilePath = Label(window, width=100,text=path)
    JMFilePath.grid(column=1,row=2)
```

You have already created the label, here you just need to set its text attribute :

```
def JMfileBrowser():
    stfiletypes = (('text files', '*.xlsx'),('All files', '*.*'))
    path= filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=stfiletypes)
    if path:
        JMFilePath.config(text=path)
```

Do the same in the other function :

```
def QRGfileBrowser():
    stfiletypes = (('text files', '*.xlsx'),('All files', '*.*'))
    path= filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=stfiletypes)
    if path:
        QRGFilePath.config(text=path)
```

Your code will run just fine.